# Having problems with HTML5 Video and javascript using the DOM loadstart

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering a strange error, when I migrate some sample code from W3Schools to JSfiddle. I have the same error in an actual project and can't solve it. Why doesn't it work? No error message just nothing happening

http://jsfiddle.net/E7FhU/64/

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onloadstart = function() {
    alert("Starting to load video");
};
```